# MAVEN_OPTS setting in windows

Tags: windows, maven

How to set up the maven opts parameter in windows whose equivalent in mac is export MAVEN_OPTS="--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED"

1 - i tried cmd SET MAVEN_OPTS="--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED"
2 - i tried add system environment
but during maven clean install getting error module jdk.compiler does  not export com.sun.tools.javac.parser to unnamed module